# How to develop Liferay project in Eclipsce juno and built it on on Jboss

Tags: jboss, liferay, liferay-ide

I have downloaded the Liferay 6.1 with jboss 7.1.1 Bundle and Liferay IDE(Eclipsce Juno).All I have to do is to develop Liferay Project and running it on Jboss server.

I can able to run and open liferay portal in localhost:8080/

I am having issues in developing Liferay portal project.As default server adapter for Liferay in IDE is Tomcat 7.0 and I couldn't able to find Jboss server adapter.I tried by running and deploy it on Tomcat and running the Jboss server by running standalone.bat file.

Please advise and help in develop and running Liferay project on Jboss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay IDE is meant for development with Tomcat only since tomcat's start-up time, its simple structure and comparatively easy configuration makes it ideal for a development environment.

If you are development plugin projects like themes, portlets, hook, layouts etc then if it works on tomcat it would work on any other server running with Liferay, so during development you can use tomcat and then when you have completed your development iteration (i.e. when your project is ready to be deployed for testing or for stage environments) you can deploy the WAR to Jboss for testing and can do some testing to see if it works fine.

Since the plugins are made in such a way as to be independent of the underlying Server, there should not be any issues developing them on Tomcat and then running them on Jboss.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try as you said. Thanks

Comment: Also can i please know whether any issues may come during deploy the war file to Jboss.

Comment: Till date I have not found any issues deploying WARs on Jboss for Liferay plugins which were developed on Liferay IDE. But for `EXT-plugin` (we had done some heavy customizations of taglibs and core impl classes) we had encountered some class-loading issues which I didn't see on Tomcat, since the architecture for Jboss 7.1.1 has changed a lot from Jboss 5.1. So I guess you need not worry if you are not doing any heavy customizations with `EXT-plugin`.

Comment: As I am a newbie to completely this,I need some guidance.Do you have any link or steps on executing these steps.

Comment: but what if you want to use javaEE features?

Comment: @PrakashK In the plugin war file I deploy my portlets I want some EJBs to handle my db layer.

Answer (score 1):

There's [guide in Liferay Wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Non-Tomcat+Server+Bundles) about developing with non-Tomcat Liferay bundles. There you can read about the disadvantages of that kind of development and how to do it if you still want.

But I agree, developing with Tomcat is definetely the better idea.

Comment: Yes, I followed as that in the guide but I couldn't able to run it

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it through a work around, steps mentioned @ https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17864836

Benefits of Liferay IDE plugin+ JBoss as runtime configured in IDE.
Only issue is you'll need to use any other eclipse based IDE which supports JBoss AS 7.1.1 as normal server/runtime (like JBoss Developer Studio).