# How to deploy portet developed in Liferay Tomcat bundle to Jboss bundle

Tags: tomcat, jboss, liferay

I am currently developing my liferay portlets in Tomcat bundle 6.1.1.I need to deploy the developed portlets to liferay Jboss bundle and running it. Please help in executing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12576268/468763), I have provided a detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576521/468763) to that question which might help you.

But I will mention in short to answer your question:

1. There is no change the way a plugin would be deployed on Tomcat or Jboss, they both accept WAR files.
2. So you need only create WAR files for your portlets through the plugins SDK, with are created inside the `/plugins-sdk/dist` folder
3. Then deploy it on a running JBOSS i.e. copy the created WAR files of the portlets to the directory `/liferay_home/deploy/` and liferay will deploy it.

**Edit** - Another approach:
On the other-hand if you want to build and deploy directly through the `plugins-sdk` i.e. through `ant` commands then you would have to change the `build.<machine-name>.properties` to point to `Jboss` instead of the `Tomcat` bundle.

I would suggest the first approach, since you would already have a working `WAR` then why to again build it from `ant` and then deploy.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I created the war in /plugins-sdk/dist folder.I started the liferay with jboss but I cannt able to find the portlet in it.

Comment: Managed by Liferay IDE (remove this comment to prevent future updates)

#Managed by Liferay IDE (remove this comment to prevent future updates)
#Wed Sep 26 14:51:48 IST 2012
app.server.portal.dir = D:\\Liferay\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27\\webapps\\ROOT
app.server.lib.global.dir = D:\\Liferay\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27\\lib\\ext
app.server.deploy.dir = D:\\Liferay\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27\\webapps
app.server.type = tomcat
app.server.dir = D:\\Liferay\\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.27

Comment: Do I need to edit the build.machinename.properties file inside pluggins folder for jboss

Comment: Oh you mean you also want to ***`build`*** the portlet through `ant` and then deploy on `JBOSS`? If you want to deploy the portlets through `ant` on `Jboss` then ***Yes***, you would have to change the properties as mentioned by you to point to Jboss instead of tomcat. I thought you already have developed portlets, then just create the WAR of those portlets and copy the WAR file to the directory `/liferay_home/deploy` and start the server.